# Rails 3 Will_Paginate With Ajax Not Updating Partial

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, response, will-paginate

I'm attempting to add some ajax to my pagination using the will_paginate gem as specified in [Pagination With Ajax](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax) and I got it up to the point where I can see the correct HTML response in Firebug but it doesn't actually render the new code oddly enough.

Here's my simplified code:

index action

```
def index  
  @videos = Video.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page =>  per_page
end
```

index.html.haml

```
#box_content{:style => "padding: 1em;text-align:center;"}
  = render "video
```

_video.html.haml

```
- @videos.each do |video|
    %iframe{:width=>"200", :height=>"150", :src=>link_src(video.link), :frameborder=>"0", :allowfullscreen =>"true"}
%div.pageinfo
    = will_paginate @videos
```

Application.js

```
$(function () {  
    $('.pagination a').live("click", function () {  
        $.get(this.href, null, null, 'script');  
        return false;  
    });  
});
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#box_content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render("video")) %>");
```

Nothing happens at all when I click on the will_paginate links, if I look at the network GET response I see the following which does indicate a new page:

```
$('#box_content').html("<iframe allowfullscreen=\'true\' frameborder=\'0\' height=\'150\' src=\'http://www.youtube.com/embed/z52V60aZ7ro\' width=\'200\'><\/iframe>\n<div class=\'pageinfo\'>\n  <div class=\"pagination\"><a class=\"previous_page\" rel=\"prev start\" href=\"/?_=1339623038312&amp;page=1\">&#8592; Previous<\/a> <a rel=\"prev start\" href=\"/?_=1339623038312&amp;page=1\">1<\/a> <em class=\"current\">2<\/em> <a rel=\"next\" href=\"/?_=1339623038312&amp;page=3\">3<\/a> <a href=\"/?_=1339623038312&amp;page=4\">4<\/a> <a class=\"next_page\" rel=\"next\" href=\"/?_=1339623038312&amp;page=3\">Next &#8594;<\/a><\/div>\n<\/div>\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was actually getting a Javascript error. I didn't see it in my Firebug console because the Javascript was being rendered as html and not javascript. Executing the response javascript in the firebug console manually let me see the error however.